# File not getting transferred to SFTP with key file authentication in tFTPPut inTalend

Tags: sftp, talend

I am using tFTPConnection to connect to SFTP using a public key file and I am successfully able to connect to it.
[image] 
[image]
The string MYFilename is been set inside the tJava

[image]
I need to transfer few files from local to SFTP. I am using a tFTPPut for this purpose.
[image]
.However, when I am connected to SFTP, using a password authentication, I can successfully transfer all the files. But when I connect using the Key file, I gets the 'No Match File Exists' error and no files are transferred.
I don't know what I am missing in the code.
 Please help.
The error which I receive is as below- 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Meen,

Based on the info you provided and the screenshots your issue is based on your configuration and distribution and of your keys.  To connect to an SFTP server using the public key method you must first generate a public/private key pair.  Then you must have your public key installed on the server.  In your Talend job the private key value should be context.private_key (with the path to your actual private key).  You are pointing to your public key (context.public_key).  If your private key has a passphrase (you should always use a pass phrase when generating public/private key pairs) then you must enter this as well.

Talend will then use your private key to generate a signature.  The server will use your public key to authenticate the signature. This is used in place of a password. It is more secure but more difficult to setup.

The other thing is, before setting up any type of FTP in Talend, always use a client (like WINSCP) to first work out any connection kinks.  Its much easier to debug the basic connection and authentication issues that way.  Once you know it works, transfer the proper setting to Talend and any issues from that point forward are much easier to solve.

You may have other issues as well, but based on the info you provided this is where I would start.

Comment: The key file which I am using is a private key.(Sorry I named the context variable wrongly). Its a .key file.
I am able to connect to the SFTP successfully but not able to transfer any file.
I get the below error - 
Exception in component tFTPPut_18
2: The system cannot find the file specified. 
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2297)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:1750)

Comment: please replace the context.public_key with the true path using the file select control Talend provides.  It could simply be a.wrong path,  b. incorrect syntax in path context variable, c. Talend does not have access right to path.  are you running on windows or unix?

Comment: I tried replacing the context.public_key with the true path even. But still receiving the same error. I am running on Windows.
The key file I am using is .key file since .ppk is not accepted by Talend. Because when I tried using the .ppk file, Talend threw the 'invalid key' error. So, I am now using the .key file.

Comment: i will experiment and get back to you.  in the meantime any luck getting it to work with WinSCP? sometimes the error messages are very misleading.  If you can get it working with WINSCP using same key then issue is with Talend.

Comment: Actually, my initial job was in SQL using batch files( WINSCP) but since last few months we were facing regular failures. Hence, we planned to migrate the job to Talend.
Thanks for your help.